# Open pdf from string in default browser viewer

Tags: angular, pdf

I recieve pdf file sended by backend, which looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%Çì¢
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
xµXKo7k'¶§EÚéã¨£ÀS¢(éZ´(Ð[ÒzHz
EÂÎ!¿4#ivµF·{Fâ7||äPºUzT:þæÁÛáÇWN}ø4¿»C\ev¢`½rXÝ½Þ¿(ðh "ù¯Øùi1áFÛ¸bÓL`£Ùå×yõó?ÃËúÂjÙØQE
jè¢| ªØ
ºÎ
```

etc

I have to open it in the new window after recieving response from server.

i have request method

```
generatePdf(workflowId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
      `api/workflow/tax-deduction/${workflowId}/3ndfl-preview`,
      {observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
      )
      .catch(this.handleError(workflowNT.ERROR_GENERATE_PDF_REPORT));
  }
```

But what should i do next ? How am i supposed to handle rceived string from server to show it as a pdf file ?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe this method, get the response and make a blob out of it -

```
var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})

var link = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Now that you have the source, use any pdf-reader like **ng2-pdf-viewer** to view it in the browser.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: So there are no any ways to view pdf except various libraries ? Actually my task was to exclude ng2-pdf-viewer due to its unstable work in IE11

Comment: Try this - `<embed src="link" 
    style="width: 100%;height: 500px" 
    type="application/pdf">` in your template. This should work.